# Accessing curtain wall panels properties in c# for autodesk design automation

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

I tried to access the curtain wall panels Host properties like below in C# but its inaccessible, is there a way to do it? I really appreciate your help on this.

```c#
// Curtain walls
var cwp = new FilteredElementCollector(doc)
        .OfCategory(BuiltInCategory.OST_CurtainWallPanels)
        .WhereElementIsNotElementType()
        .ToElements();
                
foreach (var p in cwp)
{
   var cwpCategoryName = p.Host.Category.Name; // Error, Element does not contain a definition for 'Host' and no accessible extension method ...
   var hostId = p.Host.Id;
   var cwpName = p.Host.Name;
   var assemblyCode = p.Host.WallType.LookupParameter("Assembly Code").AsValueString();
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just on a side note, you can completely eliminate the call to `ToElements`. It has nil advantage in this case, and disadvantages using memory, coding (thinking) space and processing time. Unfortunately,  I cannot say why the `Host` does not deliver what you want. I would suggest snooping the live BIM in Revit desktop using [RevitLookup](https://github.com/jeremytammik/RevitLookup) et al. and searching interactively for the required data.

Comment: Thank you @Jeremy for the revitlookup help, I saw the Host in the revitlookup is under the FamilyInstance that is why I cannot access it by just doing the above code, thanks also to this [link](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-api-forum/family-instance-filter/td-p/7287113) which I needed to cast it to FamilyInstance. I can now access the Host.

However, I needed to access the WallType which is under the Host how can I do it?